# Parallel Processing and Disk IO for performance. More cores or more servers?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, hpc

I have a large analysis job on an AWS EC2 instance (c3.8xlarge) on Ubuntu 12.04.

The objective is to load the server at 100% CPU, running as many jobs as memory allows (varying amounts but generally 1-3gb per job).

My initial thought was to provision a large instance and run 32 simulataneous processing jobs - one per core. However these jobs do a lot of reading from files (very often the same file), a lot of gzipping/unzipping, and basically a lot of disk-heavy stuff.

Previously when I ran a test on the m3.xlarge node (15gb RAM, 4 cores), I could get a very nice 100% utilisation of CPUs for 4 simultaneous jobs.

However my initial results on 32 cores with 60gb RAM are much worse. I suspect the server is bottlenecking hard on the disk, which is currently general purpose SSD (not provisioned IOPS).

So the question is - what is better here? Do I try to provision higher IOPS for the disk, or try some kind of RAID set-up so that the big server can handle more jobs? Or am I always going to get better overall throughput by simply starting up several smaller servers in a cluster without the disk bottleneck of running 30+ jobs simultaneously on one disk?

Not an HPC expert here so all advice gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using instance storage rather than EBS? Instance storage is ephemeral but it should give you the best outright performance. The performance can be up to 5x better: https://gist.github.com/ktheory/3c3616fca42a3716346b Also, what does CloudWatch say about your EBS volumes, is that suggesting EBS is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best" is dependent, of course, but there are a few well known ways to boost IO performance on AWS.

- RAID0-together a bunch of General Purpose SSD EBS volumes.
- A few, large, provisioned IOP EBS volumes.
- If you're doing sequential work, use the 640GB of Instance Local storage you have with that type.
- A combination of the above three points.

All of the above presumes your instance is running in EBS-Optimized mode.

You certainly can get max-IOPS on Amazon, you just need to be willing to pay for it. I don't believe you can attach instance-storage after instance creation, so that option may require spinning up a new instance.

Comment: Thanks for this, great suggestions which I will investigate now. Am I likely to be able to achieve the performance I need over simply running smaller machines with fewer jobs that have less 'per job' demand on the disk?

Comment: @monkeymatrix Good question. In general, scaling single-threaded processes goes mostly-linearly assuming the only contended resource is CPU. These days one-big-box scales more efficiently than lots of little boxes, but you can scale *farther* with lots of little boxes. Lots of little boxes won't be AWS-cost-efficient though.

Comment: You were correct - instance store is much, much faster than EBS and I'm seeing very little bottlenecking simply by putting the data on the ephemeral drives. Accepted with thanks.